# AWS Lambda keeps returning the default response on a new function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS lambda. Following a youtube tutorial, I created a test lambda function to simply return "True", but it keeps returning the default response:
Response:
{
"statusCode": 200,
"body": ""Hello from Lambda!""
}

Comment: Can you paste the code here ?

Comment: def lambda_handler(event, context):
      return True

Comment: did you deploy your code in lambda (there is an option to deploy code)? How are you testing this ? Is it through aws console ?

Comment: For me it returned the boolean True with same code. You might have not deployed the code before testing it.

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't deploy it. #newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously there is used to be save in lambda. But now it actually changed to deploy. You need to basically deploy your code inorder to test it.

Please refer this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-lambda-sam.html